# customised listview using arrayadapter class in android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listview

how to select row item using Tick mark like iphone in android?iam using imageview in list_row.xml.when i click the list row item then i show image in row imageview.

```
if(getItem(position)!=null){
img.setvisibilty(View.Visible);}        
else{System.out.println("imagenull");}
```

iam using this but image display in last row only.please help me how to select item using tickmark image.

```
public class DistanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Constant>{
public static String category,state,miles;
public ImageView img;
private Context context;
private int current = -1;
ArrayList<Constant> dataObject;

public DistanceArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
ArrayList<Constant> dataObject) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, dataObject);
this.context=context;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View rowView=convertView;
if(rowView==null){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, parent, false);

}
    //TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    //textView.setText(""+getItem(position).id);
textView1.setText(""+getItem(position).caption);
img=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if(position%2==1)
{
rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.even_list);
}
else
    {
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.odd_list);
    }
```

rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(img.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
            {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("1");
            }
if(img.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
System.out.println("12");
}

miles=getItem(position).caption;
System.out.println("miles"+miles);
}
});
return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: you want to display row with tick mark image ...? Means all row??

Comment: yes.when click row then only display tick mark image in row not all row onlyselected row

Comment: Divya Solved Your Problem or not ??

Comment: no i tried your logic but tick mark image display only in last item of row in listview.i want to display image in select row item.

Comment: @DivyaBalraj check the answer below. Its the solution give by Romain Guy google developer. Check the link in the answer

Comment: Raghunandan i want to display tick image without checkbox click event.when i click the row item in listview i want to display tick image in row this concept like iphone listview selection display tick mark

Comment: can you give me arrayadapter code ??

Comment: @DivyaBalraj i don't know how it works in iPhone but this solution is given by a google developer and i suggest you stick with it unless you have a better solution

Comment: Bhupendrasinh i updated the arrayadapter code

Comment: @DivyaBalaraj you can set a image as background to your check box

Answer (score 2):

Drawing from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    String[] GENRES = new String[] {"Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama", "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"};
    private CheckBoxAdapter mCheckBoxAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mCheckBoxAdapter = new CheckBoxAdapter(this, GENRES);
        listView.setAdapter(mCheckBoxAdapter);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < GENRES.length; i++) {
                    if (mCheckBoxAdapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                        result.append(GENRES[i]);
                        result.append("\n");
                    }

                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, 1000).show();
            }

        });
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mCheckBoxAdapter.toggle(position);
    }

    class CheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        String[] gen;
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;

        CheckBoxAdapter(MainActivity context, String[] genres) {
            super(context, 0, genres);
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(genres.length);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gen = genres;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return gen.length;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <ListView
 android:id="@+id/lv"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/button1"/>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the XML file for the checkboxes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

When you click the button a toast message with  list of item choosen is displayed. You can modify the above according to your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set selection mode on your ListView

```
    //if using ListActivity or ListFragment
 getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    //or

     myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    //myListView is reference to your ListView
```

Comment: what's the effect of single and multiple choice for the TS case?

Answer (score 0):

1.Make visibility `gone` to you tick mark image

2.Implement `view.setOnClickListener` in `arrayadapter`.

3.In that check `image.getVisibility()==View.GONE` then make `image.setVisibity(View.Visible)`

4.if `image.getVisiblity()==View.VISIBLE` then make your `image.setVisibity(View.GONE)`

Try this.