# Strange ListView behaviour in Android with Checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView` with a `CheckBox` and two `TextView` widgets. When I click a `CheckBox` and I scroll my `ListView` I see a strange behavior. Some `CheckBox` widgets are randomly, automatically selected. Is it because the objects are reused? I'm so confused.

I have checked many other posts here regarding this question like updating the state in `getView()` or using `OnCheckedChangeListener`, but still this behavior is not going.

Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Less story more code please :)

Comment: This sounds very much like you are not properly handling the recycling of `ListView` items. The list adapter's code would be useful...

Comment: I have recently observed the same behavior when scrolling in some of my ListViews with checkboxes. I don't have a solution, just wanted to say that it's apparently a common issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. you can check this link. The solution by Romain Guy