# Android Custom adapter with CheckBox: setOnClickListener or setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom adapter with a Checkbox in the layout. Can I use setOnClickListener on a CheckBox without problems or is better use setOnCheckedChangeListener?

The code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private boolean[] selected;

public MyAdaptader(Context context, List<Object> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    selected = new boolean[list.size()];
}

private OnClickListener pressed= new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
            selected[(Integer)v.getTag()] = true;
        else
            selected[(Integer)v.getTag()] = false;
    }
};

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fila, null);
    }
    TextView txtName=convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);
    chkSelected.setTag(position);
    txtName.setText(getItem(position).toString());
    chkSelected.setChecked(selected[position]);
    chkSelected.setOnClickListener(pressed);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

I use onClick and seems to work, but the is better an onCheckedListener?

P.D.: there is not ViewHolder to simplify the code

Comment: post your code and describe your problem clearly

Comment: what do you want to do. Do you need to get the elements when checkbox is clicked

Comment: i want that the user can select and deselect elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. check the answer in the link. the user can select deselect the check box also retrieve items selected.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a copy & paste example. I want to know the reasons of use one or other listener. Something like Boli-CS answer.

Comment: Use the answer in the link as a reference and check out the differences. Also the link posted in the answer has a good discussion on the topic. Solution was given by Romain Guy who is a google developer on the android team. I would suggest using setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to use setOnCheckedChangeListener. setOnClickListener will be called only when you click the button, if you change the state of the checkbox without clicking, for example, call the setChecked() in your code, setOnClickListener will not be called but setOnCheckedChangeListener will be called.

Answer (score 1):

When you set both `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and `setOnClickListener` events:

1. If you *swipe* a `Switch`, it will call `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.
2. If you *click* the `Switch`, it will call `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and `setOnClickListener`. In this case you can get a weird behaviour, when the first listener toggles some variable and the second listener toggles the same variable again.

So, it would be better to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in all cases.

If you have `android:clickable="false"` inside the `Switch`, it won't work without `setOnClickListener`, so you can add this empty listener or remove `android:clickable="false"`.