# How to get value of a textView field corresponding to the selected checkBox in android in a listView

Tags: android

I have a `listView` that has 3 `textViews` fields and a `check box` in ever `row.<br`>
If a particular `checkBox` is selected or checked then how to access the details in that row (or the values of the corresponding `textViews`) corresponding to the checked `check box`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. check this. Might help

Answer (score 1):

This solution is worked for me.

In Your View getView() under the BaseAdapter class add below code.

```
public static boolean checked=false;

   holder.your_checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

                if(cb.isChecked())
                {
                    checked=true;
                    String  selected_txt = object_of_ArrayList.get(position).get(ArrayList.Value);

                // For Example//

                 String name=friendList.get(position).get(FriendList.FRIEND_NAME);
                }

            }
        });
```

If you want use this item text in another activity then you want make string as static like that

```
   public static String name;
```

If you want access this name in another activity

```
  String str_name=your_adapterName.string;
```