# How do I get the status of the check boxes (checked / unchecked) from this listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

How do I get the status of the check boxes (checked / unchecked) from this listview after the list has loaded?

I know how to check when the list is loading by overriding the getview method of the adapter, but this is not the case.

What I need is to get the status after the list has loaded and the user checks / uncheckes items in the list and hits the backup or delete button from menu.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is way too vague.. 
Only thing I can answer with the amount of info you gave is to put that in your adapter:

```
chkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBox);

    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkBox checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
               "result:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like that

```
 @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ViewHolder holder = null;
       Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

       if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
       holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
       convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
          Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
           " is " + cb.isChecked(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
         }
        });
       }
       else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       Country country = countryList.get(position);
       holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
       holder.name.setText(country.getName());
       holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
       holder.name.setTag(country);

       return convertView;

      }
```