# Set which boxes are checked in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have my Adapter for the ListView and everything runs fine in the main activity. The listview is a list of all the apps with checkboxes next to each of them. Currently when I run the app, some of the checkboxes are randomly checked; where do I define which boxes are or are not checked upon startup? Is it in the main activity or in the Adapter?

Comment: Please add the piece of code where you have created the checkboxes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. check this might help

Answer (score 0):

`where do I define which boxes are or are not checked upon startup? Is it in the main activity or in the Adapter?`

AFAIK you can define it in the adapter. To see how, you can check the following tutorial:

[Android ListView Checkbox Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the getView() method of your array adapter:

```
@Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(row_layoutxml_id, parent, false);
    CheckBox cb = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    cb.setChecked(true/false);
    ...
}
```