# listview checkbox state not saved properly

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with checkboxes. I use SharedPreferences to save the state of every checkbox but when i reopen the application not the same checkboxes are checked. I think there is something wrong with letting the program know whick checkbox is selected but I can't figure out how to fix it.

The MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private List<EmployeeModel> employee;
private EmployeeAdapter adapter;
CheckBox button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    employee = new ArrayList<EmployeeModel>();

    fillData("Nishant", "Shah", 25, false);
    fillData("Chirag", "Shah", 22, false);
    fillData("Utsav", "Kapuriya", 22, false);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new EmployeeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simplerow, employee);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void fillData ( String name, String lastName, int age, boolean isSelected ) {
             final EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel();
             model.setName(name);
             model.setLastName(lastName);
             model.setAge(age);
             model.setSelected(isSelected);

             employee.add(model);
}
```

EmployeeModel.java

```
public class EmployeeModel {

    private String name;
     private int age;
     private String lastName;
     private boolean selected;

     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

     public int getAge() {
      return age;
     }

     public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
     }

     public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
     }

     public boolean isSelected() {
      return selected;
     }

     public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
      this.selected = selected;
     }
```

My Adapter

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     public List<EmployeeModel> employeeData;
     private Context mContext;
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     Editor editor;

     public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<EmployeeModel> objects) {
         this.employeeData = objects;
         this.mContext = context;
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
      ViewHolder holder;

      if (convertView == null) {
          holder = new ViewHolder();

          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

          holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          holder.chkTick = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

          convertView.setTag(holder);
      } 
      else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

      final int pos = position;
      holder.txtName.setText(employeeData.get(position).getName() + " " + employeeData.get(position).getLastName());

      holder.chkTick.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
      holder.chkTick.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              employeeData.get(pos).setSelected(isChecked);
              editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+pos, isChecked);
              editor.commit();
          }
      });

      return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {
         TextView txtName;
         CheckBox chkTick;
     }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623 check this might help

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I tried to do something similar and it seemed that  the parameter position of the getView function was not right.

I had to override the getCount function in the adapter to get the correct value. Apart from that i see nothing wrong in your code.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return employeeData.size();
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It didn't work...I think there is something wrong with getting the position of the right checkbox.

Comment: You could try to add the var position inside the oncheckedchangelistener. Maybe the holder is getting recycled and when the checkbox is clicked the position is not the one youre looking for. Make a copy of the variable position inside the listener class and use that var for the sharedpref.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but that failed too!I tried to put some System.out.print to the code and I saw that the boolean values are saved properly for the right position. So I guess the problem has to do with trying to retrieve the checkbox state when the app starts again.